# Downgrading Precision Touchpad to regular

Tags: windows-10, touchpad

I just got a new laptop and it has a precision touchpad (Synaptics LuxPad v1.3). I don't use gestures, so I really don't need the features.

The precision touchpad doesn't work with some programs I use; I read that it emits different events, so I'd like to make it behave like a normal touchpad.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: "read that it emits different events" - What did you read exactly?  "I'd like to make it behave like a normal touchpad." - Typically not installing the Synaptic drivers will do this.

Comment: @Ramhound: Re: different events: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/7134034/, https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=517187 comment 15. Also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25552748/no-mousewheel-events-on-surface-pro-3-with-ie11

Comment: I am not going to try to identify the statements, if you want to edit your question, and quote them thats fine.